# Deploy several cod files to Blackberry Simulator

Tags: deployment, blackberry

I know we can deploy a cod file to blackberry simulator using:

```
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test.cod")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("updates.force")
```

What about deploying several cod files? Seems fledgecontroller cannot deploy a zip file. So it won't help even I zip all cod files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Ray! Here is the trick:

```
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test.cod.pending")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-1.cod.pending")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-2.cod.pending")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-3.cod.pending")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-4.cod.pending")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("updates.force")
```

Now I don't have any trouble to deploy several cod files.

Comment: Why does naming the cod files .pending make a difference? For me it has been working with just .cod

Comment: Those files are actually ended with .cod extension, I guess .pending here just let fledgecontroller decide if cod files are completed.

Comment: Aha, I just found this on the blackberry devblog. .pending tells the simulator this is a hot swap. http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/04/new-code-hot-swap-feature/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to copy the zipped cod file to the simulators home directory and it will be deployed when you launch the simulator.

For the fledgecontroller (interactive mode) approach you will need to load each individual cod file.
For example:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator>fledgecontroller.exe
Connecting to Fledge session "8900"... connected.
LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test.cod")
LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-1.cod")
LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-2.cod")
LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-3.cod")
LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-4.cod")
LoadCod("updates.force")
```

*Updates.force isn't normally required, as echo pointed out LoadCod already does an update. I've left this in case it's important on the older simulators.

Or from the simulator gui use:

```
file --> load java program (and repeat this step for each of the cod files above)
```

Fledgecontroller batch mode:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator>fledgecontroller.exe /session=8900 /execute=LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-1.cod")
D:\Program Files (x86)\BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator>fledgecontroller.exe /session=8900 /execute=LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-2.cod")
D:\Program Files (x86)\BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator>fledgecontroller.exe /session=8900 /execute=LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-3.cod")
D:\Program Files (x86)\BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator>fledgecontroller.exe /session=8900 /execute=LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test-4.cod")
D:\Program Files (x86)\BlackBerry\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\simulator>fledgecontroller.exe /session=8900 /execute=LoadCod("D:\\temp\\test.cod")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much!

Copy the zipped cod file or cod files to the simulators home directory is not a good idea. Since restart simulator is really slow...

I was using

```
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test.cod")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-1.cod")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-2.cod")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-3.cod")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("C:\\temp\\test-4.cod")
fledgecontroller /session=9800 /execute=LoadCod("updates.force")
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe I have to deploy cod files one time, instead of calling fledgecontroller for several times. I am not sure, have to give it a shot on Monday.

Comment: hmm, yes, it's working for me in interactive mode but not batch with the commands you pasted. Perhaps it's syntax and we're missing something along the lines of a ; to get all files on the same input line for batch.

Comment: I can see it recognizes mutiple /execute= on a single batch line. Could it be a bug with batch mode?

Comment: Maybe because the simulator updates after each execution of LoadCod, and it considers every cod file as a complete one. It might be good if we have some command such as updates.pause.

Comment: I think when I tried this yesterday I must have made a typo or something because it is working for me in batch mode. The same commands. I'll update my post

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comments about a bug and multiple executes on one line as they were both wrong :)

Comment: I saw your update. Thanks! So you mean if we load test.cod at last, it will work?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter the order in which they are loaded and I have tried both. I think the syntax you have now is correct, it should be working. I'll upload my cod files to http://reboot.org.uk/so/20110111/ in case what remains is something specific to your app.

Comment: Thanks, seems the problem is I got cod files by converting a jar file, and those cod files are not standard ones.

Comment: Well, if I deploy cod files for more than 1 time, the app is gone.

Comment: So if you duplicate one of the fledgecontroller commands it fails? I didn't try that but I will have a go later to see if I get the same thing.

Comment: Exactly! I also wonder how we can remove an app from simulator so that we may avoid this.